# Error while running the django server in eclipse

Tags: django

```
Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runserver
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.).
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how are you tryin to run django server in eclipse ?

Comment: why odoo tag, is it related to `odoo-10` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the “runserver” flag in what ever setting determines to run manage.py to actually start the server.

E.g

python manage.py runserver

Or to run on a specific port.

python manage.py runserver 1234

Comment: You need to have Django installed. If you are using a virtual env, activate it and run pip install -r requirements.txt. Else just use pip to install Django. @mani